# Retrieve data in javascript from jquery post

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I want to  perform a post action in the client side  to call a  javascript based webscript(server side ) in order to delete and element and do  more stuff.

If i perform in the  client side a post call like this

```
var data = {
  option: "erase",
  noderef: 5832
};

$.post(Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + "extractor-jdocs",
  data, 
  callback_function);
```

How can i manage to read "data"  in the server side? (javascript)

Comment: This makes no sense. You are making a _background_ request here, there is no one around who would care to execute any JavaScript in this environment. Plus, client-side JavaScript doesn’t even have access to POST data. Please go read [ask], and then  edit your question to first of all describe what you are actually trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call repo webscript/server side webscript from client side js.

```
var data = {
  option: "erase",
  noderef: 5832
};
Alfresco.util.Ajax.jsonPost(

{

                url: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + "mypostwebscripturl",

                dataObj:data,

                successCallback: {

                                fn: function(res){

                                   alert("success");

                                   alert(res.responseText);                                                                                            

                                },

                                scope: this

                },

                                failureCallback:

                                {

                                   fn: function(response)

                                   {

                                                  // Display error message and reload

                                                  Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayPrompt(

                                                  {

                                                                 title: Alfresco.util.message("message.failure", this.name),

                                                                 text: "search failed"

                                                  });                                          

                                   },

                                   scope: this

                                }

});

},
```

pass your data to **dataObj** like `dataObj:data`

and create post webscript and you can get your post parameters in your server side/data/repo webscripts like this

`var param1 = json.get("noderef");`

and do what you wanted to do .